# What kind of string is this? How do I unserialize this string?

Tags: php, string, serialization, deserialization

What kind of string is this? How can I unserialize it and get the array out of it?

```
a:2:{i:0;s:7:"Abogado";i:1;s:7:"Notario";}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get this data from your db or this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php  ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a serialized string. You can unserialize it with this function: [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), like this:

```
$str = 'a:2:{i:0;s:7:"Abogado";i:1;s:7:"Notario";}';
print_r(unserialize($str));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Abogado [1] => Notario )
```

**Side Note:**

A quote from the manual:

> **Warning:**
>   FALSE is returned both in the case of an error and if unserializing the serialized FALSE value. **It is possible to catch this special case by comparing str with serialize(false) or by catching the issued E_NOTICE**.

> **Warning:**
>   Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize(). **Unserialization can result in code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading, and a malicious user may be able to exploit this**. Use a safe, standard data interchange format such as JSON (via json_decode() and json_encode()) if you need to pass serialized data to the user.

Answer (score -1):

I used this:

```
$argument = 'a:2:{i:0;s:7:"Abogado";i:1;s:7:"Notario";}';
$arr = unserialize(urldecode($argument));
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: The `urldecode()` makes no difference here.