# Retrive answer_id in php

Tags: php

Below are my database value and i want to retrieve answer_id using php.

```
a:1:{i:0;O:8:\"stdClass\":7:{s:11:\"question_id\";s:1:\"1\";s:13:\"question_text\";s:18:\"This is question 1\";s:9:\"answer_id\";s:1:\"2\";s:11:\"answer_text\";s:4:\"asss\";s:11:\"points_base\";s:1:\"2\";s:6:\"points\";s:1:\"2\";s:15:\"custom_response\";s:0:\"\";}}
```

Comment: See:[What kind of string is this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28614078) and [How can I access an object/array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30680938)

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issues is that your serialized String contains back-slashes which would mess with the serialized object. Solution: Remove the backslashes and unserialzed the string and you'd get your object back:

```
    <?php


        $strSerializedWithSlashes       = 'a:1:{i:0;O:8:\"stdClass\":7:{s:11:\"question_id\";s:1:\"1\";s:13:\"question_text\";s:18:\"This is question 1\";s:9:\"answer_id\";s:1:\"2\";s:11:\"answer_text\";s:4:\"asss\";s:11:\"points_base\";s:1:\"2\";s:6:\"points\";s:1:\"2\";s:15:\"custom_response\";s:0:\"\";}}';
        $strSerializedWithoutSlashes    = str_replace("\\", "", $strSerializedWithSlashes);
        $objUnSerialized                = unserialize($strSerializedWithoutSlashes);

        var_dump($objUnSerialized);


        // DUMPS::
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[1]
              public 'question_id' => string '1' (length=1)
              public 'question_text' => string 'This is question 1' (length=18)
              public 'answer_id' => string '2' (length=1)
              public 'answer_text' => string 'asss' (length=4)
              public 'points_base' => string '2' (length=1)
              public 'points' => string '2' (length=1)
              public 'custom_response' => string '' (length=0)
```

You can test it here: https://eval.in/571535

And now; to get you answer_id You can simply do this:

```
    <?php


        $objData    = $objUnSerialized[0];
        $answerID   = $objData->answer_id;

        var_dump($answerID);  // DUMPS: '2'
```

Comment: @vishal Anytime Mate... **;-)**  You may check this as the answer so that someone with similar issues can see what worked for you though...

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, it will return answer id to you.

```
$str = "a:1:{i:0;O:8:\"stdClass\":7:{s:11:\"question_id\";s:1:\"1\";s:13:\"question_text\";s:18:\"This is question 1\";s:9:\"answer_id\";s:1:\"2\";s:11:\"answer_text\";s:4:\"asss\";s:11:\"points_base\";s:1:\"2\";s:6:\"points\";s:1:\"2\";s:15:\"custom_response\";s:0:\"\";}}";
$arry = unserialize($str);

echo $arry[0]->answer_id;
```