# How can I parse this string? (about wordpress)

Tags: php, string, wordpress, parsing

I wanna parse this code:

`a:4:{s:7:"arrival";i:1472256000;s:9:"departure";i:1472342400;s:6:"adults";s:1:"1";s:9:"childrent";s:4:"None";}`

I wanna get the 1472256000 and 1472342400 with PHP. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/unserialize

Comment: It's a serialized array. Use `unserialize`. http://php.net/unserialize

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28614078/3933332

Comment: $var = unserialize( $string ); echo $var['arrival']; echo $var['departure'];

Comment: I found `wordpress` tag in question. That's why I'm suggesting [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize)
 `

Comment: Thanks all of you :)

Comment: Who has up-voted this question and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a serialized string. So all you have to do is [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) it.

```
$str = 'a:4:{s:7:"arrival";i:1472256000;s:9:"departure";i:1472342400;s:6:"adults";s:1:"1";s:9:"childrent";s:4:"None";}';

$str = unserialize($str);

echo $str['arrival'];

echo $str['departure'];
```