# PHP Parsing content from code in cart

Tags: php, parsing

I have some module that created custom shopping cart.

When i add products to cart - database content for **cart** is:

```
a:3:{
    s:8:"products";
    a:7:{

        i:10;
        a:3:{
            s:10:"product_id";
            i:10; <- product id
            s:6:"amount";
            i:2; <- amount of product
            s:5:"price";
            s:6:"1.2500"; <- product price
        }

        i:11;
        a:3:{
            s:10:"product_id"; 
            i:11;
            s:6:"amount";
            i:9;
            s:5:"price";
            s:7:"1.2500";
        }
    }

    s:3:"sum";
    d:2.5000; <- this is total sum of cart
    s:6:"amount";
    i:49; <- this is total amount of products
}
```

I want to create PHP script which parses details from code above. I need to take content from each a:3:{ ... } and display product id, amount, price in **table view**

I am absolutely new in php parsing and don't know where to start. Have read some manuals, but it's still far from completing the task. Anyone can help?

Comment: This looks like serialized data so you could parse it using `unserialize()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28614078/3933332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database content looks like a serialized array. Use unserialize on this serialized data to access it properly:

> http://php.net/manual/function.unserialize.php

In order to display the contents in the table use the array access mechanisms of PHP. More information here:

> http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php