# How to unserialize this kind of String in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this kind of string and all I know is serialized.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:12:"Sample array";i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:5:"Apple";i:1;s:6:"Orange";}}
```

I didn't find much examples on the web, except php docs or php questions. Not sure it's a common way to serialize it or has a special name. My question is, how to unserialize this string with Dart?

The actual string I'm dealing with is this and I can't unserialize it with [some web tools](https://www.unserialize.com/s/75dc92f9-b08c-68e9-5bb0-0000196d2c90).

```
"a:2:{s:6:\"monday\";a:3:{i:3;a:6:{s:4:\"show\";s:12:\"side-by-side\";s:9:\"from_hour\";s:2:\"01\";s:12:\"from_minutes\";s:2:\"00\";s:7:\"to_hour\";s:2:\"02\";s:10:\"to_minutes\";s:2:\"00\";s:2:\"id\";s:39:\"monday_dcb5a1b146e20461d8234c13bd3b11b3\";}i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"show\";s:21:\"the-joe-finnegan-show\";s:9:\"from_hour\";s:2:\"08\";s:12:\"from_minutes\";s:2:\"10\";s:7:\"to_hour\";s:2:\"09\";s:10:\"to_minutes\";s:2:\"00\";s:2:\"id\";s:39:\"monday_6ce0d6f821031d782273713b293e8861\";}i:2;a:6:{s:4:\"show\";s:9:\"lets-talk\";s:9:\"from_hour\";s:2:\"11\";s:12:\"from_minutes\";s:2:\"00\";s:7:\"to_hour\";s:2:\"12\";s:10:\"to_minutes\";s:2:\"00\";s:2:\"id\";s:39:\"monday_ea6562913d78053a9dcad09762b9892d\";}}s:7:\"tuesday\";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"show\";s:12:\"side-by-side\";s:9:\"from_hour\";s:2:\"01\";s:12:\"from_minutes\";s:2:\"00\";s:7:\"to_hour\";s:2:\"03\";s:10:\"to_minutes\";s:2:\"00\";s:2:\"id\";s:40:\"tuesday_1acd9974eae192dcff5b72141e65dda2\";}}}"
```

And here's a related question, seems so simple on the php side.
[What kind of string is this? How do I unserialize this string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614078/what-kind-of-string-is-this-how-do-i-unserialize-this-string)

Comment: You can write your own parser and use it. It is easy.

Comment: @mezoni deadlines, my friend, deadlined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a translation to Dart of [Nicolas Chambrier's](https://github.com/naholyr/js-php-unserialize/blob/master/php-unserialize.js) javascript implementation to unserialize PHP strings.

Given a [serialized string in php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php), translates and returns a **Map<String, dynamic> object**.

Here is a direct link to the class [php_unserialize.dart](https://github.com/rodrigoc85/dart-php-unserialize-string/blob/main/lib/php_unserialize.dart), and you can also check how to use it [here](https://github.com/rodrigoc85/dart-php-unserialize-string).

Usage:

```
String _sample = 'O:8:"stdClass":5:{s:4:"name";s:7:"Rodrigo";s:4:"last";s:7:"Cardozo";s:3:"age";i:35;s:9:"developer";b:1;s:6:"height";d:73.5;}';

var object = Php.unserialize(_sample);  

print(object["name"]);
```